# Problem with displaying HTML content after in_array

Tags: loop, array, count

I'm trying to create layout based on [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/249901/want-to-separate-sections-of-posts-can-you-restart-loop) question and answer.

First of all, it took me ages to understand why if there's only one post in the category, it's not showing up - so I found out that counting should start from 0, not 1 ;)

But I can't figure out why HTML after `in_array` is not displayed at all?

I tried to move `<div class='grid'>` above `<article></article>` but this obviously doesn't work, because that causes every article being wrapped with grid...
Here's the code:

```
     <?php
     if (have_posts()) :
        while (have_posts()) :
            the_post();
            $total_posts = $wp_query->post_count;
            $current_post = $wp_query->current_post;

            // Large boxes
            if (in_array($current_post, array(0, 6))) : ?>

                <article class="large">
                    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>  
                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                </article>
           <?php
           elseif ($current_post > 0 && $current_post < 6 || 
           $current_post > 6) :
                // This should open a grid container but it doesn't
                in_array($current_post, array(1, 7)) ? "<div class='grid'>" : "";    //This syntax is new for me ?>
                <article>
                    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>  
                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                </article>
                <?php
                // This should close a grid but it doesn't
                in_array($current_post, array(6, $total_posts)) ? "</div> <!-- .grid -->" : ""; //This doesn't close a grid container
                //This doesn't display a new container
                $current_post == 6 ? "<div class='new-container'></div> <!-- .new-container-->" : "";

            endif;

        endwhile;
    endif;
?>
```

What I see now:

- article.large
- article
- article
- article
- article
- article
- article

---

What I want to see:

- **article.large**
- **div.grid**

  article

  article

  article

  article

  article

  article
- **/div.grid**
- **div.new-container**

--

- **article.large**
- **div.grid**

  article

  article

  article

  article

  article

  article
- **/div.grid**
- **div.new-container** and so on

---

If it was just a basic loop (without a blue container) I could style the posts with nth-child formula, but I need to place this container in between the groups of posts... and I was hoping that above code would help me to achieve this, but it doesn't place this additional container :)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**Notice that there are no `echo` statements, so nothing will be output. You need to echo the result, or nothing will be sent to the browser**.

> If it was just a basic loop (without a blue container) I could style the posts with nth-child formula, but I need to place this container in between the groups of posts... and I was hoping that above code would help me to achieve this, but it doesn't place this additional container :)

It doesn't place the container because you never `echo` the result. Instead it's silently discarded because nothing was done with it.

E.g.

```
$colour = 'red';
// this will not do anything
( $colour === 'red') ? "it's red" : "it is not red";

// but this will:
echo ($colour === 'red') ? "it's red" : "it is not red";
```

Some tips going forward:

- In general, avoid ternary operators, and keep in mind that they simply act as a value replacement, you still have to do something with the result.
- Try to stick to the `() ? :` version as it makes it clearer which bit is the test as it's in brackets
- Keep in mind that using nested or adjacent ternary operators can get confusing very quickly, e.g. what is the value of: `$test = true ? true ? "a" : "b" : "c"`, very confusing.
- In other languages, the order is reversed, so instead of `condition ? true : false` it's `condition ? false: true`, which gets confusing
- When counting you can probably get away with CSS grids/flex/nth-child selectors

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your explanation sounds like a black magic for me, but as I understood, this is a wrong approach, so I'm going to follow your advice;) What I want to achieve is to wrap X number of posts in a container, than place something else e.g. widget, and again show X number of posts, repeat... As you said, I can easily style the elements inside the wrapper, but I believe that I still need to use some kind of counter to wrap X number of posts. What I like in above solution, is that it didn't break even if there are not X number of posts, but less...

Comment: ... every other solution I found, required the exact number of posts in the database, otherwise divs didn't close etc.

Comment: That's not true, the CSS nth-child rule lets you apply styles to children based on the count, e.g. every other row has a blue background, or every 6th item has pink text etc

Comment: Also keep in mind that you might not need a containing div at all

Comment: I understand this, but you are talking about the situation, when there are only posts inside the loop. I want to have X number of posts, something else (not a post, for example widget), again X number of posts. So I guess I need to stop the loop after X number of posts, place another container outside the loop, start the loop again from post X+1... or am I missing something?:)

Comment: I think we've wandered outside of your original question and are discussing something else. Perhaps you should open a new question as it sounds like you have a more fundamental problem you're trying to solve. If this answers this specific question you asked up top though, consider marking it as an accepted answer

Comment: I upvoted your answer because it's useful, but I believe it doesn't fully answer my question. You assumed that I just want to style the elements inside the defined containers - this is partially true and I agree that it can be done with nth-child, but what I really need, is to add a new container with something inside, so the code   $current_post == 6 ? "<div class='new-container'>Some custom code here</div> <!-- .new-container-->" : "";   is the most important for me...

Comment: Not at all, the root problem is that you never used an `echo` statement, I simply suggested you use CSS instead as a way of sidestepping the entire problem. If you read my answer again, the majority of it talks about how there is no `echo` statement. In essence, all the music is playing but the speaker cable is unplugged. You've put `?:`, you needed `echo ?:`

Comment: @Anda I've restructured and emboldened my answer so that the sentences at the end about CSS don't seem so overpowering, and the bits at the beginning are more obvious